# Have there been any interesting results or studies of "manifolds" whose dimension is not constant?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

For example, imagine a stack of papers that gradually gets sanded down to one sheet of paper as you look further and further to the right. Then the left side can be described as a 3-dimensional "manifold" while the right side is a 2-dimensional "manifold". We could describe the two figures separately, as two manifolds of different dimensions joined by a set of (spatial/volume-wise) dimension 1 (which itself fails to be a 1-dimensional manifold if it's a segment and not a loop) all embedded in 3-dimensional space. But are there any interesting mathematical results or descriptions that have emerged from considering this shape as a whole and not decomposing into parts? Shapes that locally look like Euclidean spaces, but the Euclidean space can vary depending on the point chosen?

Comment: The dimension is necessarily constant on each connected component of the space. So the 3-dim piece and the 2-dim piece could be studied separately by known methods. And if you insist that your space is connected, then it is not a manifold. Which is to say that there likely isn't anything "interesting" to be discussed there.

Comment: Mathematically, this is not a mainfold, because at the border between three dimensions and two dimensions, the neighborhood of the points are neither homeomorphic to $2$ or $3$ dimensions. You can view this space as the union of two manifolds with boundaries, glued together on the boundary.

Comment: The phrase "locally look like Euclidean spaces, but the Euclidean space can vary depending on the point chosen" actually implies that the dimension is constant. In your example, what happens "locally" at a point on the line where the pile is a one paper think  plane side and solid on the other?

Comment: Yes, if you fold a piece of (practically) 2D paper like a fan, you will end up with a 3D object. Are you familiar with fractals?

Comment: You might be interested in [stratified spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thom-Mather_stratified_space)?